# error with Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCom in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i have a problem with my web application. I don't know how resolve this. here is  my browser

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwLnN.png)

thanks

Comment: You should provide more information (what are you trying to do, was it working before, when stopped working, what have you tried to do to solve it, etc.) so people can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Try using `Install-Package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` on Package Manager Console, or copy the file from local project if it doesn't exist on server. Your message contains `Could not load file or assembly`.

Comment: @dime2lo , i tried use hangfire for cron job. and i modified my web.config. before, application works. for repair i have tried the install Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform but no resolved this problem

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto thanks for your response but, this does not work